# Contenido que se desborda

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cuando el usuario presiona el boton editar, el div "pregunta-preguntaInicial" se vuelve editable, pero el problema es cuando el usuario escribe de más. El contenido se desborda y al momento de hacer enter se me genera la etiqueta 
. ¿Como podría solucionar esto?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on('click', '.editarPregunta', function(){
        let actual = $(this).parents('.pregunta-contenedor').children('.pregunta-preguntaInicial').attr('contentEditable','true').focus();
    });
    
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  /*CONTENEDOR*/
  .contenedorTotalPreguntas {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  /*PUNTAJE*/
  .puntaje {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    background: #3c8dbc;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .puntaje-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .puntaje-descripcion {
    width: 41%;
  }
  
  .puntaje-puntuacion {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /*OBSERVACIONES*/
  .observacion {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ecf0f5;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  
  .observacion-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .observacion-descripcionInicial {
    width: 33%;
  }
  
  .observacion-puntuacion {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  .observacion-descripcionFinal {
    width: 16%;
  }
  
  .observacion-i {
    width: 4%;
  }
  
  .observacion-malo {
    background-color: #fb86af;
  }
  
  .observacion-regular {
    background: #fbd386;
  }
  
  .observacion-bueno {
    background: #cdf69d;
  }
  
  .observacion-muyBueno {
    background: #cdf69d;
  }
  
  .observacion-acciones {
    /* width: 4%; */
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  
  /*PREGUNTA*/
  .pregunta {
    /* font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #333;
      height: 55px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center; */
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-contenedor {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    height: 49px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 49px;
  }
  
  .pregunta-preguntaInicial {
    width: 33%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  
  .pregunta-comboBox {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /**/
  select {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  option {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /**/
  
  .pregunta-radioButton {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /**/
  input[type="radio"] {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /**/
  
  .pregunta-text {
    width: 16%;
  }
  
  /*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/
  
  .text {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 230px;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
  }
  
  /*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/
  
  .pregunta-subirArchivo {
    width: 4%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-iconos {
    /* width: 4%; */
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  /**/
  .pregunta-iconos img {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  /**/
  
  /*btn-pregungta esta afuera del contenedor "pregunta"*/
  
  .btn-pregunta {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  /*btn-pregungta esta afuera del contenedor "pregunta"*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>index 6</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="index6_2.css">
    <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas">
        <div class="puntaje">
            <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion">PUNTAJE</div>
            <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div>
            <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div>
            <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div>
            <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="observacion">
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i">i</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pregunta">
            <div class="pregunta-contenedor">
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA</div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox">
                    <select class="comboBox">
                            <option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>
                            <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
                            <option value="Media">Media</option>
                            <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><input class="subirArchivo" type="submit" value="i"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarPregunta" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="EliminarPregunta" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="btn-pregunta" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA PREGUNTA">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo podrias solucionar poniendo un `input:text`, en vez de dejar solo el div y rellenar su contenido, ademas de que seria lo mas correcto para que el usuario ingrese datos

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on('click', '.editarPregunta', function(){
    let actual = $(this).parents('.pregunta-contenedor').children('.pregunta-preguntaInicial').children('input').focus();
});

});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  /*CONTENEDOR*/
  .contenedorTotalPreguntas {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  /*PUNTAJE*/
  .puntaje {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    background: #3c8dbc;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .puntaje-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .puntaje-descripcion {
    width: 41%;
  }
  
  .puntaje-puntuacion {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /*OBSERVACIONES*/
  .observacion {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ecf0f5;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  
  .observacion-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .observacion-descripcionInicial {
    width: 33%;
  }
  
  .observacion-puntuacion {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  .observacion-descripcionFinal {
    width: 16%;
  }
  
  .observacion-i {
    width: 4%;
  }
  
  .observacion-malo {
    background-color: #fb86af;
  }
  
  .observacion-regular {
    background: #fbd386;
  }
  
  .observacion-bueno {
    background: #cdf69d;
  }
  
  .observacion-muyBueno {
    background: #cdf69d;
  }
  
  .observacion-acciones {
    /* width: 4%; */
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  
  /*PREGUNTA*/
  .pregunta {
    /* font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #333;
      height: 55px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center; */
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-contenedor {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    height: 49px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 49px;
  }
  
  .pregunta-preguntaInicial {
    width: 33%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  
  .pregunta-comboBox {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /**/
  select {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  option {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /**/
  
  .pregunta-radioButton {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /**/
  input[type="radio"] {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /**/
  
  .pregunta-text {
    width: 16%;
  }
  
  /*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/
  
  .text {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 230px;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
  }
  
  /*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/
  
  .pregunta-subirArchivo {
    width: 4%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-iconos {
    /* width: 4%; */
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  /**/
  .pregunta-iconos img {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  /**/
  
  /*btn-pregungta esta afuera del contenedor "pregunta"*/
  
  .btn-pregunta {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  /*btn-pregungta esta afuera del contenedor "pregunta"*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>index 6</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="index6_2.css">
<!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas">
    <div class="puntaje">
        <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion">PUNTAJE</div>
        <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div>
        <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div>
        <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div>
        <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div>  
    </div>
    <div class="observacion">
        <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div>
        <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div>
        <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div>
        <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div>
        <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div>
        <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div>
        <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div>
        <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i">i</div>
        <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pregunta">
        <div class="pregunta-contenedor">
            <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial"><input type="text" placeholder="Aqui puede colocar su pregunta!"></div>
            <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox">
                <select class="comboBox">
                        <option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>
                        <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
                        <option value="Media">Media</option>
                        <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
            <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
            <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
            <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
            <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div>
            <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><input class="subirArchivo" type="submit" value="i"></div>
            <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarPregunta" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="EliminarPregunta" title="Eliminar">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn-pregunta" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA PREGUNTA">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

De todas formas, para que funcione de la forma que vos queres tendrias que agregar `word-break: break-all;`

```
.pregunta-preguntaInicial {
width: 33%;
justify-content: flex-start;
padding: 0 15px;
word-break: break-all;
}
```

Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 0):

Estuve experimentando y me di cuenta que al ponerle display:flex a un contenedor con texto hace que este se salga de su contenedor y siga de largo, pero si lo dejamos en display: block, este respetara el contenido y seguira dentro. Además, tambien me fije que cuando aumentaba el contenido, el contenedor iba aumentando su tamaño pero no bajaba, solo se quedaba en en centro, entonces me di cuenta que era por el tamaño del padre, le habia puesto 45px al igual que los otros, le cambie la propiedad a auto y FUNCIONO!!!!!